# Slugger utility

Tags: shell-script, awk, files, logs

Implement a shell script program that provides the following functionality.

It takes a log file as input. The log file contains the log statements with message stamp as shown on the side.

The utility lists out all the actions that took more than the specified time. The time is specified in seconds from the command line.

Sample Input Log File:

```
#<process id> <date time> <log level> <file name> <line number> <actual message>

1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 WARN db_util.c 5928 Config file not found, using default values
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connected to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 ERROR log_test.c 198 Unable to setup our satellite launch system
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:21 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnected. Initialize to launch the satellite.
```

Ex:If the utility is executed by giving the above file as input and 2 seconds the performance threshold time, it should produce the following output.

Sample Output:

```
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite
```

So far I have tried:

```
awk -F' ' '! /#.*$/ {print $3}' $1 | awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{t=$1" "$2; "date -d \""t"\"  +%s"|getline d; print $1,$2,d}' $1
```

Reads time column from input log file and converts in into unix timestamp.

Comment: and how this entries `15:23:09` and `15:23:18` relate? unclear

Comment: The difference between the second time and first time should be > 2 (seconds the performance threshold time).

Comment: the difference between `15:23:09` and `15:23:17` is also > 2 seconds, so what?

Comment: Difference which is grater then 2 is printed. So the the difference between 15:23:17 and 15:23:09 = 8 >2, so output line is (1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database) printed.           And the difference between 15:23:21 and 15:23:18 = 3>2, so output line         (1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite) is printed.

Comment: awk -v pthreshold=$1 '{txt_tim=mktime(gensub(/-|:/," ", "g", $2" "$3))} 
NR>1 && txt_tim-prevtxt_tim>pthreshold{print prevrecord} 
{
 prevtxt_tim=txt_tim; 
 prevrecord=$0
}' $2                                                                                                                            This is code i have tried, is there a some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think you need to recode the dates:

```
awk '{split($3, p, /:/); if (prev && (prev + 2) % 60 <= p[3]) {
      print line}; prev=p[3]; line=$0}' logfile
```